# adjust text lenght for a column in crystal reports

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am stuck with like how to make adjust the width of the column and later If the length of the column increases the rest should come in the next line.

But here the total text is coming in a separate line .Which is not looking good.

For you reference Below.The description text is not coming in the same line as other fields. its coming in the second line separately and its extending in stead of getting split up and display the rest in the next line.

Please help me out with this in crystal reports.

```
Description                        CategoryName     CheckNo     projectname Amount PaymentDate

                                     xerox         vvvvvv88888    sai       111,111.00  2014/03/0
aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

for value in description column apply `can grow` property.

check can grow property and give value as **0**, So that it extends

Comment: Hi siva. Really thanks for the reply.But as i mentioned its coming in the next line and its continuing straightly instead of splitting based on the available space and the rest coming in to next line.Its looks odd when we print the reports and submit to anyone.It should text wrap in the provided space for description column only.PLease help me on it.

Comment: thats fine but tell me have you tried can grow property? Also let me know you are getting this in CR itself or while exporting to any format

Comment: I have tried using can grow property.But no positive response .And i am viewing the report in crystal report viewer.And there i am facing the problem.